# cannot connect to mysql database ubuntu 20.4 (VPS) "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'"

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, vps

I am working on the setup of my first unmanaged vps(ubuntu 20.4) and following the document to connect my django site to mysql server "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database"

able to setup

1. python/django/virtualenv
2. mysql server - tested from mysql workbench on my local machine-Ok
3. apache2 working ok. able to see the welcome screen with sqlite3.

now moving to mysql. i tried both the way('ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql' and option file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' to connect to mysql server from django project.

None of the alternatives working. activated virtualenv, installed mysqldb using

a) sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
b) pip install wheel
c) pip install mysqlclient

while trying to migrate following error encountered. tried with all the option available on stakoverflow, i found none of them working.

Error:
**"
(envFusion) worker@server:~/fusion/fusionerp$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/worker/fusion/envFusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in 
import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
.
.
File "/home/worker/fusion/envFusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in 
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient? "**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

with ubuntu 20.04 deafult python version is 3.8 and connecting to mysql with 3.8 is a bit challenge so you need to downgrade python to 3.6 or downgrade to ubuntu 18 if you are starting a fresh.

Found a tutorial to downgrade using alternatives and it worked. But had my other dependencies where i need python >= 3.7. So i had no other choice but refresh my ubuntu 20.04 on vps and configured with postgres. it is working way better than i expected with apache2/restframework/redis.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that i have a solution to this problem, so when we use a Ubuntu OS, i think that we need to run the next commands to work that package:

`sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev -y`
`sudo apt-get install gcc -y`
`pip3 install mysqlclient`

Even if you already tried the first one, it might work. I have a Dockerfile in my GitHub of a Django app, if you want to test it later to see if it works on your machine, it took me a week to find the problem and deploy this app to Oracle Cloud because of this error.

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/Audrey-Teles/TORDO/blob/master/Dockerfile)